# Perl regex grouping result adding extra characters even thou not in correct group

Tags: regex, perl

During the learning process of Regex Grouping rules, one thing isn't quite clear to me. I'll show with an example.

When i run the following code:

```
$s="Text1    Text2   Text3   0";
$s =~ s/(\S+)(\s+)(.*)/$1/;
print("$s\n");
```

The result that i get is: "Text1", which is what i wanted to get. I distributed the entire string into 3 groups, and returned the first one.

However, when doing the following:

```
$s="Text1    Text2   Text3   0";
$s =~ s/(\S+)(\s+)/$1/;
print("$s\n");
```

The text i'm getting back is: "Text1Text2   Text3   0"

The difference between the two regex statements is the third group (.*). My question is, why don't we get "Text1" for the second statement as well?. After all, if examaning it, and as far as i understand, We group all "Non Whitespaces" charecters to first group, and returning it. The second group is where the spaces begin, so first group should contain only "Text1". Why do we get "Text1Text2   Text3   0" even thou the first group applies only until the "WhiteSpaces" (which is where the second group start).

Comment: You are replacing, not extracting. `.*` matches the rest of the line and all text matched is removed from the result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew And yet, your answer didn't quite explain why the (.*) matter in case of grouping. Would be happy to get an answer which explains both cases i showed. thank you.

Comment: Your second code is just removing the spaces after the first chunk of 1+ non-whitespace chars. 1) https://regex101.com/r/hXNgAT/1 2) https://regex101.com/r/hXNgAT/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` is the substitution operator. It searches for a substring that matches the regex *PATTERN* and replaces it by *REPLACEMENT*.

In `"Text1    Text2   Text3   0"` the regex `(\S+)(\s+)(.*)` matches as follows:

```
Text1    Text2   Text3   0
^^^^^
 \S+ ^^^^
     \s+ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                .*
```

`\S+` matches the first run of non-whitespace characters (so `$1 = 'Text1'`), `\s+` matches the following spaces (so `$2 = '    '`), and `.*` matches the rest of the line (so `$3 = 'Text2   Text3   0'`).

The matched substring (which is the whole string; the regex matches everything) is then replaced by `$1`, which is `Text1`.

Your second regex, `(\S+)(\s+)`, matches as follows:

```
Text1    Text2   Text3   0
^^^^^
 \S+ ^^^^
     \s+
```

`\S+` matches the first run of non-whitespace characters (so `$1 = 'Text1'`) and `\s+` matches the following spaces (so `$2 = '    '`).

This time the matched substring is just `'Text1    '`, not the whole string, so replacing it by `$1` has the effect of removing the spaces in `$2`.

The part of the string that was not matched by the pattern (`'Text2   Text3   0'`) stays the same, leaving

```
Text1Text2   Text3   0
```

as the result of the substitution.

---

All the grouping and `$1` stuff is a bit of a red herring.

Compare

```
my $s = 'abcdef';
$s =~ s/c/X/;
print $s, "\n";  # abXdef
```

and

```
my $s = 'abcdef';
$s =~ s/c.*/X/;
print $s, "\n";  # abX
```

In the second example, `c.*` matches the whole rest of the string after finding `c` (in this example: `cdef`), so that's what gets replaced by `X`.